# Stop Gimp from merging layers when de-selecting

Tags: image, layer, gimp

I am trying to create a flyer in Gimp, but every single time I paste an image and then paste another image, it automatically merges the previous image I was working on.  This is a problem because then I can't click on that image again to move it around, resize, etc.

I have tried creating the images as different layers but this did not work.

How can I make it so that I can move from image to image (object to object) without having the image I am working with merge with my original layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you paste, make what you pasted (the"floating selection") a "true" layer (*Layer  ▶ To new layer* or Ctrl-Shift-N)